# Asio C++ Post Request 400

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm using asio c++, (the standalone version) and trying to make a post request to this server. I should get 204 with the body only being "{}", that's what I get on postman, but I get 400 bad request. I must be doing something wrong with the request headers, but I'm not sure what is the problem.

```
        request_stream << "POST " << path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        request_stream << "Host: " << server << "\r\n";
        request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
        request_stream << "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
        request_stream << "Content-Length: 2\r\n";
        request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

        /* Add the body. */
        request_stream << "{}";
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]. A wireshark capture should help you see what you're sending and what's wrong with it

Comment: Thx for the help, the problem remains unsolved. Will use winapi for networking and try that way, since coding for windows anyway. But when I've inspected the received packages it was saying "400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port", so I guess it was a server side problem.

Comment: sounds like you are using http to talk to a https server, you need to change your code to use https

Comment: Oh, ok I've looked into it, seems like asio can't be used for https requests? Not sure though.

Comment: Yeah, seems I didn't really know, how low-level, asio is. I've just assumed it would be handling https as well. Turns out serialization must be done by me with asio, because it's not doing that for you.

Comment: it certainly can do ssl: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/client.cpp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere you're not showing:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s("httpbin.org", "http");

    auto path   = "/post";
    auto server = "httpbin.org";
    s << "POST " << path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    s << "Host: " << server << "\r\n";
    s << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    s << "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
    s << "Content-Length: 2\r\n";
    s << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    /* Add the body. */
    s << "{}";

    std::cout << s.rdbuf();
}
```

Prints

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 15 Feb 2022 23:49:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 348
Connection: close
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "2", 
    "Content-Type": "text/plain", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-620c3c23-1b821add2053349d29aa23cb"
  }, 
  "json": {}, 
  "origin": "163.158.203.95", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Of course remove `boost/` and `boost::` for non-boost Asio.

Comment: PS: to help you correctly author HTTP requests, consider using Beast: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16cdeabd0740a8cf